# Gradle and spock few needed tests to run

Tags: gradle, automation, spock

my question is can i run by gradle a few needed for me spock tests?

I mean not packages and classes, only tests. I know the way how i can run one test:

```
./gradlew testTask --tests "*TestName*"
```

TestTask contains only include package where tests was placed.
I tried code like this:

```
./gradlew testTask --tests "*TestName*","*TestName2*"
```

It Doesn't work.Maybe someone know how i can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#test_filtering) `--tests` is an option that you can repeat. So, you should be able to specifically pick multiple tests to run with:

```
./gradlew testTask --tests "*TestName*" --tests "*TestName2*"
```

Comment: Looks like they made life easier in Gradle 4.x :) Good finding!

Comment: It works, I have gradle version 2.x, so updated to 4.0.1. :)

Answer (score 2):

For Gradle **3.x** you can apply only one filtering rule to a single `--tests` switch. In your case I see two possible solutions:

1. You can create a wildcard that will satisfy tests you expect to run (and only them), e.g.

   ```
   ./gradlew testTask --tests "*TestName*"
   ```

   this rule will satisfy both, TestName.java and TestName2.java
2. You can create separate test tasks and apply different filtering rule to them, e.g.:

   ```
   ./gradlew firstTestTask --tests "*TestName*" secondTestTask --tests "*TestName2*"
   ```

   It is verbose, but you have a control over all filtering rules.

Please take a look to Gradle's documentation for more information: https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/java_plugin.html#test_filtering